# Using a list of pairs as an argument in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to find the value per key inputted in Prolog from an associative list. This function works but only for one pair. How can I get it to work for multiple pairs in a list?

```
  assoc([pair(K,V)],Key,V) :-
     K = Key.
  assoc([pair(K,[])],Key,V):-
     assoc([pair(K,[])],Key,V).
```

Comment: In Prolog you have *predicates*, not *functions* (they are not the same thing). If you want key value pairs, use `K-V` form. SWI Prolog has library predicates that automatically know how to handle them. What does `assoc([pair(K,[])],Key,V):-
  assoc([pair(K,[])],Key,V).` mean? It looks like an instant infinite recursion. Finally, if you have a list of key-value pairs, it would be of the form `[K-V|Rest]` where `Rest` is the rest of the list. `[pair(K,[])]` is a list with just one element. It's not clear why the value is hard coded as `[]` for that pair.

Comment: @lurker I'm trying to do it manually without the swipl pairs, and I need the value so I was trying to keep the second part of the pair(the value) blank so it would return it.

Comment: You can use what you call "SWI Pairs" and still do it manually. `K-V` is just a representation, nothing to do specifically with SWI Prolog. It's just that certain SWI Prolog predicates recognize it. You don't have to use those predicates.

Comment: @lurker Ok I see what you're saying now

Answer (score 1):

Your simple case, of just one pair in the list, could be written as follows:

```
assoc([pair(K,V)], K, V).
```

Your association is a list of such pairs. In Prolog, the simplest way to represent that is with a head-tail form: `[H|T]` where `H` is the first element and `T` is the tail or the rest of the list. In the case of a match, you shouldn't care whether there are any more elements in the list or not. So you should really write the above as:

```
assoc([pair(K,V)|_], K, V).
```

In other words, if the key of the first element matches, the value should match (and vice versa). I don't care what the rest of the association list looks like (thus, the `_`). If they don't, then this clause will fail and Prolog will test the next clause, which should check the rest of the list:

```
assoc([_|AssocRest], Key, Value) :-
    assoc(AssocRest, Key, Value).
```

In this case, I don't care what the first pair is (I've taken care of that case already). So the head is `_`.

A more canonical way to represent a key value pair is with the term `Key-Value`. So the above would become:

```
assoc([K-V|_], K, V).
assoc([_|AssocRest], Key, Value) :-
    assoc(AssocRest, Key, Value).
```